# How to replace string and preserve its uppercase/lowercase

Tags: regex, perl

I want to replace one string with the other in Perl; both are of the same length. I want to replace all occurrences of the string (case insensitive), but I want that the case of the letter will be preserved. So if the first letter was upper case, the first letter after the replacement will be upper case also.

For example, if I want to replace "foo" with "bar", so I want that

```
foo ==> bar
Foo ==> Bar
FOO ==> BAR
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Perl?

Comment: Personally, I think using two regexes is perfectly fine (and possibly more readable than the alternatives). For example, the following is a common way to strip leading and trailing whitespace from a string: `s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

[How do I substitute case insensitively on the LHS while preserving case on the RHS?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS%3f)

This is copied almost directly from the above link:

```
sub preserve_case($$) {
    my ($old, $new) = @_;
    my $mask = uc $old ^ $old;
    uc $new | $mask .
    substr($mask, -1) x (length($new) - length($old))
}

my $string;

$string = "this is a Foo case";
$string =~ s/(Foo)/preserve_case($1, "bar")/egi;
print "$string\n";

# this is a Bar case

$string = "this is a foo case";
$string =~ s/(Foo)/preserve_case($1, "bar")/egi;
print "$string\n";

# this is a bar case

$string = "this is a FOO case";
$string =~ s/(Foo)/preserve_case($1, "bar")/egi;
print "$string\n";

# this is a BAR case
```

Comment: +1 for pointer to FAQ. Note that the posted solution only works for ASCII due to of bitwise-xor. The FAQ also offers a more robust (but longer and slower) alternative.

Comment: This is a really awesome solution! It deserves hundreds of upvotes.

Answer (score 13):

[`perldoc perlfaq6`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS%3f) provides some insights:

> ### How do I substitute case-insensitively on the LHS while preserving case on the RHS?
>
> Here's a lovely Perlish solution by Larry Rosler. It exploits
>   properties of bitwise `xor` on ASCII strings.
>
> ```
> $_= "this is a TEsT case";
> $old = 'test';
> $new = 'success';
> s{(\Q$old\E)}
>     { uc $new | (uc $1 ^ $1) .
>             (uc(substr $1, -1) ^ substr $1, -1) x
>             (length($new) - length $1)
>     }egi;
> print;    # 'this is a SUcCESS case'
> ```
>
> And here it is as a subroutine, modeled after the above:
>
> ```
> sub preserve_case {
>         my ($old, $new) = @_;
>         my $mask = uc $old ^ $old;
>         uc $new | $mask .
>             substr($mask, -1) x (length($new) - length($old))
>     }
>
> $string = "this is a TEsT case";
> $string =~ s/(test)/preserve_case($1, "success")/egi;
> print "$string\n";
> ```
>
> This prints:
>
> ```
> this is a SUcCESS case
> ```

So you could use the `preserve_case()` subroutine like so. Just don't expect Unicode miracles :)

```
s[\b(abc)\b][preserve_case($1,'xyz')]ei ;
```

Comment: The same FAQ also describes an alternative implementation of `preserve_case()` that preserves the case of the substitution in case it is longer than the original replacement.

Comment: Note that, if `$old` and `$new` have the same length and case, just `s/(\Q$old\E)/$1 ^ $old ^ $new/eig` is enough. (Basically, `$1 ^ $old` extracts the case differences between `$1` and `$old`, and XORing them with `$new` adjusts the case of `$new` accordingly.)

Answer (score 6):

```
$text =~ s/\b(?:(Abc)|abc)\b/ $1 ? 'Xyz' : 'xyz' /eg;
```

If the actual list is longer, you can use a lookup table.

```
my %translations = (
   'Abc' => 'Xyz',  'abc' => 'xyz',
   'Def' => 'Ghi',  'def' => 'ghi',
   'Jkl' => 'Mno',  'jkl' => 'mno',
);

my $alt_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%translations);

$text =~ s/\b($alt_pat)\b/$translations{$1}/g;
```

But that still leaves some duplication that could be removed by deriving the lowercase versions.

```
my %translations = (
   'Abc' => 'Xyz',
   'Def' => 'Ghi',
   'Jkl' => 'Mno',
);

%translations = ( ( map lc, %translations ), %translations );

my $alt_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%translations);

$text =~ s/\b($alt_pat)\b/$translations{$1}/g;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that factors out the idea of "alter one string to match the capitalization of another string" into a function, and calls that function to build the replacement.

```
sub matchcap
{
  my ($s,$r) = @_;
  return $s eq ucfirst($s) ? ucfirst($r) : lcfirst($r);
}

s/\b(Abc|abc)\b/matchcap($1,'xyz')/ge;
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a hack, using the experimental code extended regular expression:

```
$text =~ s/\b([Aa])(?{ $n=chr(ord($^N)+23) })bc/${n}yz/
```

First, match the letter A with `([Aa])`. The following `(?{...})` contains arbitrary code, with `$^N` containing the text of the most recently captured subgroup. The 23 is the difference in ASCII codes between A and X (for upper- and lowercase), so `$n` contains the letter X with the same case as the corresponding A.

(This should not be taken as an endorsement to write code like this, but as an interesting example of this experimental regular expression.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "semi-perlish" solution that should work for arbitrary regexps *and* Unicode data:

```perl
sub adjust_case {
    my ($text, $case) = @_;
    $case .= substr($case, -1) x (length($text) - length($case));
    $_ = [ split // ] for $text, $case;
    return join "", map {
        $case->[$_] =~ /\p{Upper}/ ? uc $text->[$_] :
        $case->[$_] =~ /\p{Lower}/ ? lc $text->[$_] : $text->[$_]
    } 0 .. $#$text;
}

my $regexp  = qr/\b(abc\w*)\b/i;
my $replace = "Xyzzy";

s/$regexp/adjust_case $replace, ${^MATCH}/egp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
my %trans = (
    'Abc' => Xyz, 
    'abc' => xyz,
);
$text =~s/\b(Abc|abc)\b/$trans{$1}/ge;
```

Comment: The `/e` is useless, and you shouldn't duplicate the keys: `my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys(%trans); my $re = qr/$pat/; s/\b($re)\b/$trans{$1}/g`

Answer (score 1):

You know each string is the same length, so basically, you can:

```
index = Pos(string, oldString)
for i = index to index + strlen(oldString)
  if (oldString[i] >= 'a') && (oldString[i] <= 'z'')
    string[i] = ToLower(newString[i])
  else
    string[i] = ToUpper(newString[i])0x20
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought of this kind of solution also, just wanted to know if there is "shorter" way...

Answer (score 0):

Check character by character. If a character's ASCII value falls in uppercase ASCII values, replace with uppercase else lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat trick that uses non-destructive transliteration (available in Perl 5.14) within the result of the substitution.

```
use 5.014;
$string =~ s/\b(f)(o)(o)\b/ ($1 =~ tr{fF}{bB}r) . ($2 =~ tr{oO}{aA}r) . ($3 =~ tr{oO}{rR}r) /egi;
```

You can even shorten it if consecutive groups of letters have same replacements, e.g.

```
# foo ==> see, FoO ==> SeE, etc.
$string =~ s/\b(foo)\b/ $1 =~ tr{fFoO}{sSeE}r /egi;
```