# Regex and the characters case

Tags: regex, perl, casing

Okay, I got a rather simple one (at least seems simple). I have a multi lined string and I am just playing around with replacing different words with something else. Let me show you...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

$_ = "That is my coat.\nCoats are very expensive.";
s/coat/Hat/igm;
print;
```

The output would be
`That is my Hat`
`Hats are very expensive...`

The "hat" on the first line shouldn't be capitalized. Are there any tricks that can make the casing compliant with how english is written? Thanks :)

Comment: I guess you're not working in the paints and coatings industry? :)

Comment: first of all, do not use modifier i, if you want case sensitive.

Comment: You need to define your scope. Do you plan to use this on *many* words?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace string and preserve its uppercase/lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116434/how-to-replace-string-and-preserve-its-uppercase-lowercase)

Comment: @Nikhil I forgot to omit that. Good point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see **[how-to-replace-string-and-preserve-its-uppercase-lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116434/how-to-replace-string-and-preserve-its-uppercase-lowercase)**

For more detail go to **[How do I substitute case insensitively on the LHS while preserving case on the RHS?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS%3f)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `e` modifier to `s///` to do the trick:

```
s/(coat)/ucfirst($1) eq $1 ? 'Hat' : 'hat'/igme;
```

Comment: Not a complete solution, but it covers 'coat' and 'Hat'

Answer (score 1):

For one, you should use `\b` (word boundary) to match only the whole word. For example `s/hat/coat/` would change `That` to `Tcoat` without leading `\b`. Now for your question. With the flag `/e` you can use Perl code in the replacement part of the regex. So you can write a Perl function that checks the case of the match and then set the case of the replacement properly:

```
my $s = "That is my coat.\nCoats are very expensive.";
$s =~ s/(\bcoat)/&same_case($1, "hat")/igme;
print $s, "\n";

sub same_case {
        my ($match, $replacement) = @_;

        # if match starts with uppercase character, apply ucfirst to replacement
        if($match =~ /^[A-Z]/) {
                return ucfirst($replacement);
        }
        else {
                return $replacement;
        }
}
```

Prints:

```
That is my hat.
Hats are very expensive.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub smartSubstitute {
    my $target = shift;
    my $pattern = shift;
    my $replacement = shift;

    $pattern = ucfirst $pattern;
    $replacement = ucfirst $replacement;

    $target =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/gm;

    $pattern = lcfirst $pattern;
    $replacement = lcfirst $replacement;

    $target =~ s/$pattern/$replacement/gm;

    return $target;
}

my $x = "That is my coat.\nCoats are very expansive.";
my $y = smartSubstitute($x, "coat", "Hat");
print $y, "\n";
```