# Perl regex replace in same case

Tags: regex, perl, replace, case

If you have a simple regex replace in perl as follows:

```
($line =~ s/JAM/AAA/g){
```

how would I modify it so that it looks at the match and makes the replacement the same case as the match for example:

'JAM' would become 'AAA'
and 'jam' would become 'aaa'

Comment: Do it twice: once for 'JAM' and once for 'jam'.

Comment: @tim-pietzcker: I gues it should became `Aaa`

Comment: Yeah, I am doing it twice :) I was just wondering if there was another way

Comment: [How to replace string and preserve its uppercase/lowercase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116434/how-to-replace-string-and-preserve-its-uppercase-lowercase/3116650#3116650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$line =~ s/JAM/{$& eq 'jam' ? 'aaa' : 'AAA'}/gie;
```

Comment: This does not handle `Jam` -> `Aaa`

Comment: Also it's kinda pointless to use regex if you afterwards compare to fixed strings…

Comment: Amazing! thats it :) is that basically like an if statement inside the {} ?

Comment: @4rd2, the {} is useless in this case. Also see my example. ;)

Comment: Tomalak - what do you mean? in the example I'm just doing a literal find and replace? doesn't matter about 'Jam' 'Aaa' MacroS for the paticular application I'm using it in :) would be good to know though ;)

Answer (score 4):

Unicode-based solution:

```
use Unicode::UCD qw(charinfo);
my %category_mapping = (
    Lu  # upper-case Letter
        => 'A',
    Ll  # lower-case Letter
        => 'a',
);

join q(), map { $category_mapping{charinfo(ord $_)->{category}} } split //, 'jam';
# returns aaa

join q(), map { $category_mapping{charinfo(ord $_)->{category}} } split //, 'JAM';
# returns AAA
```

Here the *unhandled characters* resp. their categories are a bit easier to see than in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl 5 you can do something like:

```
$line =~ s/JAM/$_=$&; tr!A-Z!A!; tr!a-z!a!; $_/gie;
```

It handles all different cases of JAM, like Jam, and it's easy to add other words, eg:

```
$line =~ s/JAM|SPAM/$_=$&; tr!A-Z!A!; tr!a-z!a!; $_/gie;
```

Comment: Telling us how to handle non-uniform targets (eg `s/jam/stuck/`) would be more interesting than how to handle multiple sources (Or perhaps to make it easier, `s/jam/mit/`)

Comment: I'm curious - in these examples where is the actual string to replace with specified?

Comment: @r4d2: He took advantage that the target was uniform 'A's, `tr/A-Z/A/' translates JAM to AAA.  That is why I posted my follow-up as a more general case.

Comment: @4rd2, it's not. I'm just using `tr///` to replace all upper case letters to `A` and all lower to `a`

Comment: @Seth, what special treatment would you want from `s/jam/stuck/` anyway? Upper to upper, lower to lower? And what about `jaM`?

Comment: @Qtax: That is why I edited my comment to be `s/jam/mit/` to have the same number of letters.  Presumably `jaM` should go to `miT`.  Bonus points if it handles `s/jam/mom/`.

Comment: @Seth, that's no problem, only complication would be `s/mam/mit/`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-substitute-case-insensitively-on-the-LHS-while-preserving-case-on-the-RHS%3f

Doing it in two-steps is probably a better/simpler idea...

Using the power of google I found [this](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-5-to-6/19-regex.writeback)

```
The :samecase modifier, short :ii (since it's a variant of :i) preserve case.

    my $x = 'Abcd';
    $x ~~ s:ii/^../foo/;
    say $x;                     # Foocd
    $x = 'ABC'
    $x ~~ s:ii/^../foo/;
    say $x                      # FOO

This is very useful if you want to globally rename your module Foo, to Bar,
but for example in environment variables it is written as all uppercase.
With the :ii modifier the case is automatically preserved.
```

Comment: You did notice that that last example is Perl 6, yes?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do :-)