# Case insensitive match but matching replacement case

Tags: sed

How can I adjust `sed -e 's/(match other stuff too)[aA]/\1b/g'` to have the replacing `b` match the case of the `a` being replaced?  In this case only the single character is being replaced but the entire search can/should be case insensitive (I can address that separately with `s///I` I believe).

Comment: Some suggestions using perl here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280388/perl-regex-replace-in-same-case

Comment: Is it really only one character that you are looking to replace? if so, `sed -e 's/a/b/g' -e 's/A/B/g'` might do the trick.

Comment: @1_CR well, if it is really only one character, this would do: `sed 'y/aA/bB/'`

Comment: @1_CR I presently have duplicates as you show but am trying to avoid the repetition of the rest of the expression (question edited to clarify).

Comment: @FloHimself That led me to `sed -P '/(?<match other stuff too)a/I y/aA/bB/'` but even with the look-behind it still replaces the 'a' in match.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn 's/$/\nabAB/;:a;s/(match other stuff too)([aA])(.*\n.*\2(.).*)/\1\4\3/;ta;P' file
```

Append a lookup table to the end of the line and loop until all lookups have been substituted.